# Vuetify: How to fix a v-menu at given position?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a `v-menu` like below:

```
<v-menu
  fixed
  :absolute="false"
  :close-on-click="false"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  :position-x="10"
  :position-y="200"
  :value="true"
>
  <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#first')">FIRST</v-btn>
  <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#second')">SECOND</v-btn>
  <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#third')">THIRD</v-btn>
</v-menu>
```

But when I scroll down, the menu is scrolling and thus can't be used.

How to fix it at given x/y position ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that by default, v-menu components are detached and moved to the root of your application. To fix it , you have to use the attach prop

Add v-menu inside an enclosing div and give it an 'id'. Now you can attach the menu to the id using 'attach'. Refer vuetify docs for attach.

```
<div id="attachId">
  <v-menu
    fixed
    :absolute="false"
    :close-on-click="false"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :position-x="10"
    :position-y="200"
    :value="true"
    attach="#attachId" // See this
  >
    <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#first')">FIRST</v-btn>
    <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#second')">SECOND</v-btn>
    <v-btn text block @click="$vuetify.goTo('#third')">THIRD</v-btn>
</v-menu>
```